# Rotate an image left and right at normal speed in Javascript (raphael)

Tags: javascript, image, rotation, raphael

I have made the following code:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;

if (w>=960) {
    window.direction = -1;
} else {
    window.direction = 1;
}

window.onresize=function(){
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if (w>=960) {
        window.direction = -1;
        var angle=0;
    } else {
        window.direction = 1;
        var angle=0;
    }
    console.log(window.direction);
};

window.onload = function() {  
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 730, 750);

    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('tandwiel-1'), 240, 240);
    var tandwiel1 = paper.image("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-mini-deepcolour-png/32/Wheel.png",0,0,240,240); 

    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('tandwiel-2'), 240, 240);
    var tandwiel2 = paper.image("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-mini-deepcolour-png/32/Wheel.png",0,0,240,240);

    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('tandwiel-3'), 240, 240);
    var tandwiel3 = paper.image("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-mini-deepcolour-png/32/Wheel.png",0,0,240,240);

    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('tandwiel-4'), 240, 240);
    var tandwiel4 = paper.image("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-mini-deepcolour-png/32/Wheel.png",0,0,240,240);

    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('tandwiel-5'), 240, 240);
    var tandwiel5 = paper.image("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-mini-deepcolour-png/32/Wheel.png",0,0,240,240);

    var angle = 0;

    setInterval( function() {
        angle += 2;        
        tandwiel1.stop().animate( { "transform": "R" + angle }, 1000, "<>" );
    }, 150 );

    setInterval( function() { 
        angle += 2;
        tandwiel2.stop().animate( { "transform": "R" + direction * angle }, 1000, "<>" );
    }, 150 );

    setInterval( function() {
        angle += 2;        
        tandwiel3.stop().animate( { "transform": "R" + angle }, 1000, "<>" );
    }, 150 );

    setInterval( function() {
        angle += 2;        
        tandwiel4.stop().animate( { "transform": "R" + -angle }, 1000, "<>" );
    }, 150 );

    setInterval( function() {
        angle += 2;        
        tandwiel5.stop().animate( { "transform": "R" + -angle }, 1000, "<>" );
    }, 150 );
}
```

The script is made in raphael and works fine. What I try to achieve is, when changing the browser size (set in the CSS) one gear (tandwiel) rotates opposite direction.

That's also working, but when changing the browser sieze, the gear goes rotating very fast and after a while slows down and be normal. How longer you wait to change browser, the longer it rotates fast.
I thought to change `angle += 2`; into `angle -= 2` to rotate backwards, but that won't work. I have now set `{ "transform": "R" + angle }` or `- angle` to rotate backwards, but with the above problems.

I don't have a solution to solve this problem. Anybody an idea how to make this work?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 6 counts of `var paper = ...`. That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Regarding the issue: I have a feeling the `animate()` is quickly rotating back to the original rotation, then continuing the inverted rotation

Comment: @Cerbus: yes I think it also. Maybe there is a method to (re)set the values and start again (like it does as you refresh the browser??)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here:

```
window.onresize=function(){
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if (w>=960) {
        window.direction = -1;
        var angle=0; // <-- There
    } else {
        window.direction = 1;
        var angle=0; // <-- And there
    }
    console.log(window.direction);
};
```

Removing those 2 lines should prevent the wheels from spinning out of control.

Also, you should be able to massively shorten your code, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {  
    var canvas = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 730, 750);

    var angle = 0;

    wheels([
        {id:'tandwiel-1', animation:{ "transform": "R" + angle }},
        {id:'tandwiel-2', animation:{ "transform": "R" + direction * angle }},
        {id:'tandwiel-3', animation:{ "transform": "R" + angle }},
        {id:'tandwiel-4', animation:{ "transform": "R" - angle }},
        {id:'tandwiel-5', animation:{ "transform": "R" - angle }},
    ]);
}

function wheels(properties){
    for(var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById(properties[i].id), 240, 240);
        var tandwiel = paper.image("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-mini-deepcolour-png/32/Wheel.png", 0, 0, 240, 240);

        setInterval( function() {
            angle += 2;        
            tandwiel.stop().animate(properties[i].animation , 1000, "<>" );
        }, 150 );
    }
}
```

Basically, re-use functionality, instead of coding everything 5 times ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!! Appreciate that....

Unfortunately deleting those 2 lines didn't solve the problem.
Any other suggestions?

Personally I think its buffering the rotate positions and when get -angle it just rotates all that passes till it become normal flow?? But I am not that good in JS :-(

Shorten that code is a good idea, it must be lightweight.